# Tween the texture on a TextureButton / TextureRect. Fade out Image1 while simultaneously fade in Image2

Tags: godot, gdscript

Character portrait selection. Clicking next loads the next image in an array, clicking back loads the previous image. Instead of a sharp change from one image to another, I want a variable-speed fading out of the current image and fading in of the new image. Dissolve/Render effects would be nice, but even an opacity tween 100->0 / 0-> 100 in x Seconds.

I really prefer not to use multiple objects on top of each other and alternating between them for "current texture".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do Fade-in and Fade-out by animation `modulate`. Which is the simple solution.

For dissolve we can use shaders. *And there is a lot we can do with shaders.* There are plenty of dissolve shaders you can find online... I'll explain some useful variations. I'm favoring variations that are easy to tinker with.

---

### Fade-in and Fade-out

We can do this with a `Tween` object and either the `modulate` or `self-modulate` properties.

I would go ahead and create a `Tween` in code:

```
var tween:Tween

func _ready():
    tween = Tween.new()
    add_child(tween)
```

Then we can use `interpolate_property` to manipulate `modulate`:

```
var duration_seconds = 2
tween.interpolate_property(self, "modulate",
    Color.white, Color.transparent, duration_seconds)
```

Don't forget to call start:

```
tween.start()
```

We can take advantage of yield, to add code that will execute when the tween is completed:

```
yield(tween, "tween_completed")
```

Then we change the texture:

```
self.texture = target_texture
```

And then interpolate `modulate` in the opposite direction:

```
tween.interpolate_property(self, "modulate",
    Color.transparent, Color.white, duration_seconds)
tween.start()
```

Note that I'm using `self` but you could be manipulating another node. Also `target_texture` is whatever texture you want to transition into, loaded beforehand.

---

### Dissolve Texture

For any effect that require both textures partially visible, use a custom shader. Go ahead and add a `ShaderMaterial` to your `TextureRect` (or similar), and give it a new Shader file.

This will be our starting point:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

void fragment()
{
    COLOR = texture(TEXTURE, UV);
}
```

That is a shader that simply shows the texture. Your `TextureRect` should look the same it does without this shader material. Let us add the second texture with an uniform:

```
shader_type canvas_item;
uniform sampler2D target_texture;

void fragment()
{
    COLOR = texture(TEXTURE, UV);
}
```

You should see a new entry on Shader Param on the Inspector panel for the new texture.

We also need another parameter to interpolate. It will be 0 to display the original Texture, and 1 for the alternative texture. In Godot we can add a hint for the range:

```
shader_type canvas_item;
uniform sampler2D target_texture;
uniform float weight: hint_range(0, 1);

void fragment()
{
    COLOR = texture(TEXTURE, UV);
}
```

In Shader Param on the Inspector Panel you should now see the new float, with a slider that goes from 0 to 1.

It does nothing, of course. We still need the code to mix the textures:

```
shader_type canvas_item;
uniform sampler2D target_texture;
uniform float weight: hint_range(0, 1);

void fragment()
{
    vec4 color_a = texture(TEXTURE, UV);
    vec4 color_b = texture(target_texture, UV);
    COLOR = mix(color_a, color_b, weight);
}
```

That will do. However, I'll do a little refactor for ease of modification, later on this answer:

```
shader_type canvas_item;
uniform sampler2D target_texture;
uniform float weight: hint_range(0, 1);

float adjust_weight(float input, vec2 uv)
{
    return input;
}

void fragment()
{
    vec4 color_a = texture(TEXTURE, UV);
    vec4 color_b = texture(target_texture, UV);
    float adjusted_weight = adjust_weight(weight, UV);
    COLOR = mix(color_a, color_b, adjusted_weight);
}
```

---

And now we manipulate it, again with `Tween`. I'll assume you have a `Tween` created the same way as before. Also that you already have your `target_texture` loaded.

We will start by setting the `weight` to 0, and `target_texture`:

```
self.material.set("shader_param/weight", 0)
self.material.set("shader_param/target_texture", target_texture)
```

We can tween `weight`:

```
var duration_seconds = 4
tween.interpolate_property(self.material, "shader_param/weight",
    0, 1, duration_seconds)
tween.start()
yield(tween, "tween_completed")
```

And then change the texture:

```
self.texture = target_texture
```

---

**Making Dissolve Fancy**

We can get fancy we our dissolve effect. For example, we can add another texture to control how fast different parts transition form one texture to the other:

```
uniform sampler2D transition_texture;
```

Set it to a new `NoiseTexture` (and don't forget to set the Noise property of the `NoiseTexture`). I'll be using the red channel of the texture.

A simple solution looks like this:

```
float adjust_weight(float input, vec2 uv)
{
    float transition = texture(transition_texture, uv).r;
    return min(1.0, input * (transition + 1.0));
}
```

Where the interpolation is always linear, and the transition controls the slope.

We can also do something like this:

```
float adjust_weight(float input, vec2 uv)
{
    float transition = texture(transition_texture, uv).r;
    float input_2 = input * input;
    return input_2 + (input - input_2) * transition;
}
```

Which ensure that an `input` of 0 returns 0, and an `input` of 1 returns 1. But transition controls the curve in between.

If you plot `x * x + (x - x * x) * y` in the range from 0 to 1 in both axis, you will see that when `y` (transition) is 1, you have a line, but when `y` is 0 you have a parabola.

Alternatively, we can change `adjusted_weight` to an step function:

```
float adjust_weight(float input, vec2 uv)
{
    float transition = texture(transition_texture, uv).r;
    return smoothstep(transition, transition, input);
}
```

*Using `smoothstep` instead of `step` to avoid artifacts near 0.*

Which will not interpolate between the textures, but each pixel will change from one to the other texture at a different instant. If your noise texture is continuous, then you will see the dissolve advance through the gradient.

Ah, but it does not have to be a noise texture! Any gradient will do. *You can create a texture defining how you want the dissolve to happen ([example](https://github.com/GDQuest/godot-demos/blob/master/2018/09-20-shaders/shaders/masks/shards.png), under MIT license).

*You probably can come up with other versions for that function.*

---

**Making Dissolve Edgy**

We also could add an edge color. We need, of course, to add a color parameter:

```
uniform vec4 edge_color: hint_color;
```

And we will add that color at an offset of where we transition. We need to define that offset:

```
uniform float edge_weight_offset: hint_range(0, 1);
```

Now you can add this code:

```
float adjusted_weight = adjust_weight(max(0.0, weight - edge_weight_offset * (1.0 - step(1.0, weight))), UV);
float edge_weight = adjust_weight(weight, UV);
color_a = mix(color_a, edge_color, edge_weight);
```

Here the factor `(1.0 - step(1.0, weight))` is making sure that when `weight` is 0, we pass 0. And when `weight` is 1, we pass a 1. Sadly we also need to make sure the difference does not result in a negative value. There must be another way to do it… How about this:

```
float weight_2 = weight * weight;
float adjusted_weight = adjust_weight(weight_2, UV);
float edge_weight = adjust_weight(weight_2 + (weight - weight_2) * edge_weight_offset, UV);
color_a = mix(color_a, edge_color, edge_weight);
```

*Ok, feel free to inline `adjust_weight`. Whichever version you are using (this makes edges with the `smoothstep` version. With the other it blends a color with the transition).*

---

### Dissolve Alpha

It is not hard to modify the above shader to dissolve to alpha instead of dissolving to another texture. First of all, remove `target_texture`, also remove `color_b`, which we don't need and should not use. And instead of `mix`, we can do this:

```
COLOR = vec4(color_a.rgb, 1.0 - adjusted_weight);
```

---

And to use it, do the same as before to transition out:

```
self.material.set("shader_param/weight", 0)
var duration_seconds = 2
tween.interpolate_property(self.material, "shader_param/weight",
    0, 1, duration_seconds)
tween.start()
yield(tween, "tween_completed")
```

Which will result in making it transparent. So you can change the texture:

```
self.texture = target_texture
```

And transition in (with the new texture):

```
tween.interpolate_property(self.material, "shader_param/weight",
    1, 0, duration_seconds)
tween.start()
```