# Tried making collectibles in Godot but the fade out animation of the item doesn't play and the playable character bumps onto them like they're enemies

Tags: godot

So, the problem i'm struggling with is making collectibles disappear properly and making it so the playable character doesn't collide with them at all. My guess (i'm still very new to the engine) is that either the stomp mechanic of the playable character is somehow colliding with the collectibles' hitbox or i messed up the collectibles' hitbox settings.

My guess for the animation is that i missed a step while coding the animation switch, i still now pretty much nothing of the AnimatedSprite node since i've used the AnimationPlayer so far (someone has suggested me to use the AnimatedSprite node to animate 2D sprites instead of the AnimationPlayer so i'm trying it out)

Here follows a portion of the playable character's code.

```
#Stomp mechanic
func calculate_stomp_velocity(linear_velocity: Vector2, impulse: float) -> Vector2: #Schiacciare i nemici
    var output = linear_velocity
    output.y = -impulse
    return output
func _on_EnemyDetector_area_entered(area):
    _velocity = calculate_stomp_velocity(_velocity, stomp_impulse)

#Death
func _on_EnemyDetector_body_entered(body):
    _velocity.y = 0.0
    queue_free()
```

Here is instead the collectibles' code (the collectible's name is "Leaf")

```
extends Area2D

onready var _animated_sprite = $AnimatedSprite

func _process(delta):
    _animated_sprite.play("Floating")
func _on_Leaf_body_entered(KinematicBody2D) -> void:
    _animated_sprite.stop()
_animated_sprite.play("Fade")
    queue_free()
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `queue_free` will delete the node between frames. Thus, in this code:

```
    _animated_sprite.play("Fade")
    queue_free()
```

The animation does not get a chance to be seen.

---

I suggest you `yield` to the `"animation_finished"` signal:

```
    _animated_sprite.play("Fade")
    yield(_animated_sprite, "animation_finished")
    queue_free()
```

When Godot is executing the code and encounters `yield`, it will stop executing the function. And when the signal (`"animation_finished"`) is emitted, the Godot will resume the exeution. That way the animation gets to play before the node is removed.

---

*You may also want to disable the Area2D. For example: `set_deferred("monitoring", false)`. So it does no longer trigger `"body_entered"`. I will also mention that it is a common practice to use node groups to identify nodes on collision.*

Comment: It doesn't seem like the animation is showing anyway but i'm not sure wether the problem is with the animation itself or the code. Does the order in which i write the function matter? i wrote it like this: `func _on_Leaf_body_entered(KinematicBody2D) -> void:
 yield(_animated_sprite, "animation_finished")
 _animated_sprite.play("Fade")
 queue_free()
 set_deferred("monitoring", false)`     sorry if this is supposed to be common knowledge but i really have no idea of how many of godot's functionalities work

Comment: @BlindVI Godot will stop executing when it reaches `yield(_animated_sprite, "animation_finished")` and continue when the `"animation_finished"` signal happens. But will it happen? This is why I put `_animated_sprite.play("Fade")` before `yield(_animated_sprite, "animation_finished")`. By the way, if your worry is that perhaps the animation will end after `_animated_sprite.play("Fade")` but before `yield(_animated_sprite, "animation_finished")`, then worry not. The animation will not start playing while Godot is still executing GDScript.

Comment: @BlindVI Something else: `set_deferred("monitoring", false)` will disable `"body_entered"`. But why do that when you are already removing the node? The idea is to do that first. So it is disable while the animation is playing.

Comment: I have now arranged the code like this `func _on_Leaf_body_entered(KinematicBody2D) -> void:
 set_deferred("monitoring", false)
 _animated_sprite.play("Fade")
 yield(_animated_sprite, "animation_finished")
 queue_free()` but the animation still doesn't play. It just takes the time it would take to show the frames and then it disappears. Just for information, the fade out animation is just the leaf becoming transparent. I did that simply by gradually reducing the opacity on each frame. Godot should recognize it right? I don't understand what's the problem

Comment: @BlindVI You don't do the animation like that. If you are using a `AnimatedSprite`, you would need the textures with different opacity. If you are using a `AnimationPlayer` then you can animate `modulate`, only need one key frame at the start and one at the end. *Which reminds me, you could use a `Tween` instead if you wanted, see [Tween the texture on a TextureButton / TextureRect. Fade out Image1 while simultaneously fade in Image2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68765045/402022).*

Comment: Ok so the issue was the animation. Thank you for the help, i'll switch to the `AnimationPlayer` then